# .then for Firebase auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword doesn't work

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

My code for a sign up for a website is stopped always at .then for auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword.
No error, no nothing. But the auth.createUser... works, and i can see the email address in my firebase console authentication, but nothing in .then after it works

i am using javascript
and here is my code

```js
  try {
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
          .then((userCredential) => {
            console.log("during");
            const user = userCredential.user;

            const user_data = {
                email: email,
                last_login: Date.now()
            };

            set(ref(database, 'users/' + user.uid), user_data)
            .then(() => {
                console.log('User data saved successfully');
                alert('User Created!');
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error saving user data:', error);
                alert('Error creating user. Please try again later.');
            });
            
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("OOLO");
            console.error('Error creating user:', error);
            const errorCode = error.code;
            const errorMessage = error.message;
            if (errorCode === 'auth/weak-password') {
                alert('The password is too weak.');
            } else {
                alert(errorMessage);
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    }
```

i tried everything but i have no idea why it's doing this

edit:

i tried removing (userCredential) => {} part
and added a console.log to test if the .then works
it works but if i add userCredential part back, the code dies

Comment: Please edit your question to show what output you get from your `console.log` statements.